# Linear trendline appearing non-linear

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm working on creating a linear trendline from data that contains dates and another measure (volume). The goal is to create a linear trendline that shows how volume trends over time.

The data looks as follows:

```
          date  typeID  lowPrice  highPrice  avgPrice  volume  orders  \
0   2003-11-30    22.0   9000.00    9000.00   9000.00     5.0     1.0   
1   2003-12-31    22.0   9000.00    9000.00   9000.00     2.0     1.0   
2   2004-01-31    22.0  15750.00   15750.00  15750.00     9.5     1.0   
3   2004-02-29    22.0   7000.00    7000.00   7000.00    11.0     1.0   
4   2004-03-31    22.0   7000.00    7000.00   7000.00     8.0     1.0   
6   2004-05-31    22.0  15000.00   15000.00  15000.00    16.0     1.0   
10  2004-09-30    22.0   6500.00    6500.00   6500.00    27.0     1.0
```

The issue is that for some months (the interval in which the dates are stored) there is no volume data available as can be seen above, thus the following is the approach I currently take at creating a trendline from the available dates.

```
x = df2["date"]

df2["inc_dates"] = np.arange(len(x))

y = df2["ln_vold"]

plt.subplot(15, 4, count)
plt.plot_date(x, y, xdate = True)

model = smf.ols('ln_vold ~ inc_dates', missing = "drop", data = df2).fit()
intercept, coef = model.params

l = [intercept]

for i in range(len(x) -1):
    l.append(intercept + coef*i)

plt.plot_date(x, l, "r--", xdate = True)
```

However the output for this currently shows: [image: Plot]

Which clearly isn't the right trendline (seen by the beginning being non-linear).

Now I don't see how this could go wrong, as all I do in the for-loop is add constant values to an increasing integer. All I'd like to see is a linear trendline going straight from the intercept to the end.

Comment: What happens if you change `range(len(x)-1)` to `range(1, len(x))`?

Comment: @user2285236 Have tried this before, nothing changes unfortunately.

Comment: Can you please include a sample dataset as part of a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @BenG-TW I hope the edit is sufficient.

Comment: I noticed you included a `\ ` at the end of the first line (which happens when you print a pandas df and there are more than one block's worth of columns). In your code you have `"ln_vold"`. Are there additional columns that you did not copy into your sample data?

Comment: @MennoVanDijk This is still not an MCVE. What is count, what is ln_vold, what is smf.ols? Anyhow, your x is a datetime object, while your l is calculated versus the index. What you see is that the data before 2007 are not evenly spaced in contrast to those afterwards. And you have an index error as pointed out by user2285236. This is all you can say without having a sufficient description of your data structure.